# Building selenium from source in Visual Studio 2010 (errors)

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, browser

I am trying to build the source of Selenium using Visual Studio 2010.
 Here are the steps that I did:

1 download the entire  source from http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

2 Executed go bat file (waited about 3-4 minutes to complete, no errors)

3 Opened WebDriver.sln

When I try to compile the solution I get this error:

> "Error    1   error C3861: '__stosb' identifier not found C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h    13074   1   webdriver-firefox-latest"

Tons of other identical errors (at various lines).
 What is the problem?

Thanks in advance,
 Vlad

Comment: They don't use SVN anymore, so firstly you have an old copy of the solution, they use Git: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/checkout ... recheckout the solution from Git, and have another go. Also, you do have the C++ components of Visual Studio installed don't you, as well as the Java SDK?

Comment: thank you very much for clarifing things